# Does Matlab use the GPU for plotting?

Tags: gpu, graphics, matlab

I have a new laptop with a high end (GeForce GTX 770M) discrete GPU, but when I plot large amounts of data (50k+ points), it still seems quite slow and sluggish. Is Matlab using the GPU to render the graphics? If not, is there a way I can make it use the discrete GPU instead of the onboard CPU graphics?

Answer (score 2):

It will not automatically use the GPU to do normal plots.

However, if you have the parallel computing toolbox and work with a `gpuarray`, then it will in fact automatically use the GPU to make your plot.

Described in this [Mathworks newsletter: GPU programming in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/gpu-programming-in-matlab.html).

> **GPU Computing in MATLAB**
>
> Before continuing with the wave equation example, let's quickly review how MATLAB works with the GPU.
>
> FFT, IFFT, and linear algebraic operations are among more than 100 built-in MATLAB functions that can be executed directly on the GPU by providing an input argument of the type GPUArray, a special array type provided by Parallel Computing Toolbox. These GPU-enabled functions are overloaded—in other words, they operate differently depending on the data type of the arguments passed to them.

Answer (score 1):

Check this guide:

**MATLAB GPU Computing Support for NVIDIA CUDA-Enabled GPUs**

http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html

It explains what you want to know.

> **Perform MATLAB Computations on CUDA GPUs**
>
> Using MATLAB for GPU computing lets you accelerate your applications with GPUs more easily than by using C or Fortran. With the familiar MATLAB language you can take advantage of the CUDA GPU computing technology without having to learn the intricacies of GPU architectures or low-level GPU computing libraries.